# Sorting the data by orderByChild for addChildEventListener doesn't work

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database reference "BoardContent" [which can points to a set of child elements, where each child contains 3 key-value pairs]. The "BoardContent" reference is itself located under the root element.

The issue is when I want to search by "orderByChild" for the boardContent, the data retrieved has not been getting sorted.

Below is a sample of Realtime database current data:

```
{
  "Board0": {
    "BoardContent": {
      "Entity:-NHnf7hxqp5W-Pb7-YtL": {
        "-NHnf7hxqp5W-Pb7-YtL": "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",
        "timestamp": 1669461742110,
        "xxx": 2
      },
      "Entity:-NHnf86gFAkcyWLnTXkt": {
        "-NHnf86gFAkcyWLnTXkt": "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",
        "timestamp": 1669461742689,
        "xxx": 3
      },
      "Entity:-NHnf8LbmkautY7DNu_k": {
        "-NHnf8LbmkautY7DNu_k": "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",
        "timestamp": 1669461743632,
        "xxx": 5
      },
      "Entity:-NHnf8cbA4yiBmPyFsu2": {
        "-NHnf8cbA4yiBmPyFsu2": "rO0ABXNyAB1kcmF3aW5nTW9kZWxEYXRhLlBlbmNpbEVudGl0eVAZLREIo9RXAgAAeHIAFGRyYXdpbmdNb2RlbERhdGEuUGVuA0PYb7ApjnsCAAdJAAtzdHJva2VDb2xvckkAC3N0cm9rZVdpZHRoTAALZmlyZWJhc2VLZXl0ABJMamF2YS9sYW5nL1N0cmluZztMABFsaW5lVG9Db29yZGluYXRlc3QAFUxqYXZhL3V0aWwvQXJyYXlMaXN0O0wAEW1vdmVUb0Nvb3JkaW5hdGVzcQB+AANMABFxdWFkVG9Db29yZGluYXRlc3EAfgADTAAJdGltZVN0YW1wdAAPTGphdmEvdXRpbC9NYXA7eHD/hISEAAAABXQAFC1OSG5mOGNiQTR5aUJtUHlGc3Uyc3IAE2phdmEudXRpbC5BcnJheUxpc3R4gdIdmcdhnQMAAUkABHNpemV4cAAAAAJ3BAAAAAJzcgAPamF2YS5sYW5nLkZsb2F02u3Jots88OwCAAFGAAV2YWx1ZXhyABBqYXZhLmxhbmcuTnVtYmVyhqyVHQuU4IsCAAB4cERqfJhzcQB+AAlELfhreHNxAH4ABwAAAAJ3BAAAAAJzcQB+AAlEVrxsc3EAfgAJQh/YAHhzcQB+AAcAAAAcdwQAAAAcc3EAfgAJRFa8bHNxAH4ACUIf2ABzcQB+AAlEVrxsc3EAfgAJQoKhDnNxAH4ACURWvGxzcQB+AAlCtVYcc3EAfgAJRFjBqnNxAH4ACUMscWtzcQB+AAlEWsboc3EAfgAJQ343yHNxAH4ACURco3RzcQB+AAlDrGcWc3EAfgAJRF6AAHNxAH4ACUPZskhzcQB+AAlEYN+oc3EAfgAJQ/T39HNxAH4ACURjP1BzcQB+AAlECB7Qc3EAfgAJRGRUdnNxAH4ACUQQ2tBzcQB+AAlEZWmcc3EAfgAJRBmW0XNxAH4ACURnWQ5zcQB+AAlEIePmc3EAfgAJRGlIgHNxAH4ACUQqMPxzcQB+AAlEaeKMc3EAfgAJRCwUtHhw",
        "timestamp": 1669461744949,
        "xxx": 1
      }
    }

  }
}
```

And this is the important snippet of the Java code that I have used:

```
FirebaseDatabase board0ContentReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Board0").child("BoardContent");

board0ContentReference.orderByChild("xxx").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
      DataSnapshot snapshotChild =  snapshot.getChildren().iterator().next(); // first item is obtained

      System.out.println("Item Key: " + snapshotChild.getKey());   
  }

  @Override
  public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
  }
});
```

I don't want to use in my app the function "addValueEventListener" since any modification performed, the entire data collection will be returned and this consumes the time and may make the performance worse.

Note: I have used firstly to order data by timestamp key and it didn't work, and I have try to create the "xxx" key.

The Expected Result: Item Key: Entity:-NHnf8cbA4yiBmPyFsu2", Item Key: Entity:-NHnf7hxqp5W-Pb7-YtL, Item Key: Entity:-NHnf86gFAkcyWLnTXkt, Item Key: Entity:-NHnf8LbmkautY7DNu_k

Actual Result: Item Key: -NHnf7hxqp5W-Pb7-YtL, Item Key: -NHnf8cbA4yiBmPyFsu2, Item Key: -NHnf86gFAkcyWLnTXkt, Item Key: -NHnf8LbmkautY7DNu_k

Comment: Note: the root element is "https://srb-firebase-xxxx-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"

Comment: Do you really have that `public void run() {` method inside `onChildAdded` like that? I'd expect that to give a syntax error. --- What is the output if you simplify it to: `public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) { System.out.println("Item Key: " + snapshot.getKey()); }`?

Comment: Dear Frank, sorry it was a remaining code from thread object. I have remove it.

Comment: Cool. You shouldn't use a thread, as Firebase already fires its listeners in the right context (and handles all I/O off the main thread). --- Did you also try the second piece of code in my comment? You shouldn't need an iterator, as you're already listening to `onChildAdded`.

Comment: The iterator is used just to extract "the first item" from the collection returned that has more than one value.

Comment: And regarding the code, it works fine and returns the data, and the issue is not related for thread or iterator, the data just is not returned sorted.

Comment: And thank you for your suggestion to not use thread in these type of listeners.

Comment: Why do you say it is not sorted? What is the result now? What is the expected result?

Comment: The Expected Result: Item Key: Entity:-NHnf8cbA4yiBmPyFsu2", Item Key: Entity:-NHnf7hxqp5W-Pb7-YtL, Item Key: Entity:-NHnf86gFAkcyWLnTXkt, Item Key: Entity:-NHnf8LbmkautY7DNu_k

Comment: Actual Result: Item Key: -NHnf7hxqp5W-Pb7-YtL, Item Key: -NHnf8cbA4yiBmPyFsu2, Item Key: -NHnf86gFAkcyWLnTXkt, Item Key: -NHnf8LbmkautY7DNu_k